Create Catalog using graph API
I want to create a catalog programmatically, without using commerce manager. I am using this end point but I keep getting this error message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissionss.. These are my permissions: catalog_management, ads_management, business_management, whatsapp_business_management, commerce_account_read_settings, commerce_account_manage_orders, commerce_account_read_orders, whatsapp_business_messaging and I can see my owned catalogs by using this same business id but cannot create one. Am I missing something here?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/#permissions: "You need the appropriate Marketing API Access Level and must accept the Terms of Service by creating your first catalog through Business Manager." - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview/authorization#limits says access to product catalogs is "limited" with standard access (although "No Business Manager access to manage ad accounts, user permissions and Pages." doesn't sound like it would restrict catalog access?)

You say you can see your "owned" catalogs, but were those actually created by that user? (To fulfill the "must accept the Terms of Service by creating your first catalog through Business Manager" requirement.)

Does it mean every business needs to create its first catalog through commerce manager? Only then we can create another through APIs?  Also to answer the owned catalogs question, yes the catalog was created by me. So I should be able to create one through the API as well. I am kind of new with these APIs and permissions. I'll be glad if you point me to the right direction. Thanks.

I think it means the user whose access token you are using, must have created a catalog via the UI, so that they will have accepted the ToS during that process.

Then why does it throw permission error when I am using that same access token for creating the catalog? And do you think it also means that no business can use this API unless it has created a catalog using business manager? Seems like it, in order to fulfill the condition must accept the Terms of Service by creating your first catalog through Business Manager.
